# Add a phparray variable inside javascript dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, html, impromptu

I am using the impromptu jquery plugin. I have options to insert html under "html" option, but i need to populate an array of values that i get from php. Iam not able to insert it.

What i want is to populate a select box with values that are in php variable.
I tried with:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L4fcee7b/)

```
var statesdemo = {
    state0: {
        title: 'Terms of Use',
        html:'<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><tr><td><strong>Data1</strong></td><td>:</td><td id=\'Data1\'>   <select name=\'Data1\' id=\'cart_wonid\' class=\'Data1\'><?php echo $options;?> </select></td></tr></table>',
        buttons: { Cancel: false, Agree: true },
        focus: 1,
        submit:function(e,v,m,f){
            if(v){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.prompt.goToState('state1', true);
                return false;
            }
            $.prompt.close();
        }
    },
```

Update 1:

1- Main idea is dropddown list inside the popup.
2- I want to get the dropdown list data from the mysql query that i wrote in the server side ( php ). So without this popup, the idea @tomloprod suggested works perfectly. Now coming back to the popup, i can add html contents like

```
 html : '< table > < /table > '
```

But i want to insert the php variable inside it like

```
html : '< table > < ?php $myvariable ?> < /table >'
```

Comment: Iam getting error where i use the " <?php ?>" segment

Comment: what is the error? Don't ask two questions at once, one question at a time makes your question more useful to others

Comment: @JuanMendes : When i insert the PHP i get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" .  &  the Update1 is the long description of the question , bot points to the same one.

Comment: Don't ever embed PHP variables directly in JavaScript strings, they will break the JavaScript if they contain a value that must be escaped, in your case, a `'`, but could be a newline, tab. Use `'< table >'+  < ?php echo json_encode($myvariable) ?> +  '< /table >'`

Comment: Now iam getting : **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**                        ''<table class="mytable" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><tr><td><strong>Project</strong></td><td>:</td><td id=\'cart_wonid\'> <select name=\'cart_wonid\' id=\'cart_wonid\' class=\'cart_wonid\'>'+<?php echo $options?>+'</select></td></tr><tr><td>Description:</td>'

Comment: The string you are showing is not using `json_encode` as I've recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank God... i got the answer... its the " json_encode($options) " does the work.... Thanks you   stackoverflow and thanks for the support @tomloprod & Juan Mendes

Answer (score 3):

### METHOD 1: Use `json_encode` (*recommended*)

You can add a php array to a javascript array as follow:

```
var javascript_Array = <?php json_encode($php_Array); ?>;
```

---

### METHOD 2: Put elements of `php array` into `select` directly

Try doing it directly with the array in PHP; I do not really see the need to pass it to JS...

```
<select name="data1" id="cart_wonid" class="Data1">
  <?php
     $len = count($options);
     for($c=0;$c<$len;$c++){
        echo '<option value="'.$options[$c].'">$options[$c]</option>';
     }
  ?>
</select>
```

---

### METHOD 3: Put elements of `javascript array` into `select`

**HTML:**

```
<select name="data1" id="cart_wonid" class="Data1"> </select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// Define the array
var javascript_Array = []; 

// Push elements
javascript_Array.push("Hi");
javascript_Array.push("Bye");

// Get the select with id cart_woneid
var sel = document.getElementById('cart_wonid');

// Fill the "select" with the elements of array
var i, len = javascript_Array.length;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = javascript_Array[i];
    opt.value = javascript_Array[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/1dpud00v/

Comment: ok.. then just add that variable inside the "html" will work?

Comment: but how shall i add that in the "html", i added the "javascript_Array", but its not working. iam getting an emptydropdown box

Comment: This code must be added to a "<script> ... </script>" block. After you can use the `javascript_Array` as you want.

Comment: JsFiddle can not use server-side code (PHP). You are not defining the array `$options`. Try in your own application, inside your hosting, please. Anyway, your jsfiddle is incorrect. I will edit my answer...

Comment: Sorry @tomloprod : iam showing only the necessary contents. I have declared the $options in my file. And all is working fine. But when i try to bring it on the html, it fails & says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"

Comment: Thanks @tomlprod Actually i need the dropdown, inside the popup. This make use of JS, so when i tried to fill it from the PHP variable its showing the error. problem is how can i bring the array values ( inside dropdown ) into the " html " of the impromptu popup.

Comment: I edited, again, my answer. I wrote a code which I think is what do you need.

Comment: Thanks again....@tomloprod : BUT the real problem lies when i populate the select box in the JS with the values from the PHP variable. **It is the popup which is not making the above method to work** Please tell whether i need to provide more data

Comment: @mastermind I dont understand you... Sorry, really. I'll try to help you more, but I hope other people try to help you too. May I see your website?

Comment: Thanks for the support. Iam running this under localhost only.

Comment: **1**- Main idea is dropddown list inside the popup. **2**- I want to get the dropdown list data from the mysql query that i wrote in the server side ( php ). So without this popup, the idea you suggested works perfectly. Now coming back to the popup, i can add html contents like 'html : <table> </table> '. But i want to insert the php variable inside it like **<table><?php$myvariable?></table>**.

Comment: A much more robust way (so that your JS string is properly encoded) is to use `var javascript_Array = <?php echo json_encode($array_PHP) ?>`

Comment: @mastermind How is the jsfiddle supposed to know about your PHP variables?

Comment: @tomloprod The answer added by the OP shows why what you have done is not good practice, -1 until you properly escape your PHP that is going to be used in JavaScript